# Source for this kind of string formatting?

Tags: ruby

I've seen string formatting templates like these a lot of times; in sinatra, jekyll, hexo, and many other applications.

```
/user/:id/:name
/post/:slug
```

I've seen the source of the three programs I mentioned above, but each have their own implementation, and they doesn't refer to any kind of source or specification. What is its name, and who originally created it?

Comment: Unrelated to programming issues.

Comment: I believe there's no common spec, people just implement routing like that because they've worked with it before and it's familiar.

Comment: Rails uses this URL format since 2005. Maybe because you can easily convert these to symbols and [use them as hash keys](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).

Comment: @Laf yeah, probably, it's only for my curiosity, not to solve a problem. Do you have a suggestion where I should ask these kinds of questions?

Comment: @Stefan So this kind of format is basically popularized by rails? The `:symbol` syntax does suggest that this originated from ruby.

Comment: @parchment well, Rails *is* written in Ruby so this choice seems obvious. I've asked Nicholas Seckar (routing was his [contribution to Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/core/alumni/)) about the origins of the colon-syntax yesterday. His reply: *"I don't think it was inspired by any other framework. I do not remember who suggested it first; DHH and pragmatic Dave both had a lot of input into routing."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an official spec. In the rails guides, they are referred to as "bound parameters" or "segments": http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters